# What is faster, multi delete or delete multi table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

What is faster this

/*delete user tree points */

```
delete from tb_tree_points where user_guid=P_user_guid ;
```

/*delete  tb_user_setting */

```
delete from tb_user_setting where user_guid=P_user_guid ;
```

or

```
delete from tb_tree_points as s left outer join tb_user_setting  as u
on u.user_guid=s.user_guid
where u.user_guid=s.user_guid=P_user_guid ;
```

as one query

Comment: Try both on your system with your data to see which is faster.

Comment: my data is too small , two query gives the same time
Also, I ask if I make a lot of joins not just between two tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit more of a comment.  The correct format for the second query is more like:

```
delete s, u
    from tb_tree_points s left outer join
         tb_user_setting u
         on u.user_guid = s.user_guid
    where u.user_guid = P_user_guid ;
```

Assuming that you have an index on `user_guid` in both tables, I would expect both queries to be quite comparable.  There is probably a bit more overhead in using the `join` version.  It has the advantage of being a single statement and hence a single transaction (depending on the storage engine).

The two-statement version has the advantage of simplicity.  It should be faster if you don't have the appropriate indexes (two full table scans rather than nested loop joins).  And, it is standard SQL supported by all databases.

Comment: I already have no index
So, the Two separated delete command is faster than Joins 
Also, I need to delete about 15 table or more

..........right?

Comment: @nesreen . . . If you have to delete from a bunch of tables, I would recommend doing a separate delete statement for each one.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to run them in a single transaction, 2 queries is better. If they are in one query, you'll hold locks on both tables while data from both tables is deleted; in the separate queries version you will release the lock on the first table and then acquire lock on the other one.

If you are interested in performance, I assume you are going to perform this operation with larger data sets. If the dataset is small it doesn't matter - as you say they both take the same time. If it's large however, I will be more interested in how much time the tables will be locked. Because of this, I would run the queries in loop, with some limit, to allow other queries to be run while the operations is performed. Again, this depends on the requirements - can you afford deleting only some of the records. If you have to delete everything in single, atomic transaction, then the only option is to compare the queries with a real-size data set and to see if there is considerable difference.